# Convert multiple .xls files into .csv python

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, xls

I need to convert a lot of files from .xls to .csv files.
I tried to use loop to make it:

```
excel_files = glob.glob("A/2018/*xls")

for excel in excel_files:
    out = excel.split('.')+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_excel(excel)
    df.to_csv(out)
```

And i got error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-a04c590b0fd7> in <module>
      1 for excel in excel_files:
----> 2     out = excel.split('.')+'.csv'
      3     df = pd.read_excel(excel)
      4     df.to_csv(out)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Which variables and how I can change?

Comment: `.split` returns a list, if you want to get the file name, you should use `excel.split('.')[0]+'.csv'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this. In particular, the [`pathlib.Path.with_suffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) method provides a simple way of changing the file extension.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

excel_files = Path("A/2018").glob("*xls")

for excel_file in excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    out_path = excel_file.with_suffix(".csv")
    df.to_csv(out_path)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for response but this method also not working for me. This time I have error: TypeError: cannot parse from 'PosixPath'

Comment: Where is this error? You might have to use `pd.read_excel(str(excel_file))` and `df.to_csv(str(out_path))`